# Pin Secondary tile on another page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create secondary tile. but it should pin at some other location not on start page. I have control from where I want to pin the link on some other page. Is it possible. If yes could you please tell me how can we do it.

Thanks in anticipation
Kam

Comment: What "other page" would you want to pin a secondary tile to?

Comment: you need to illustrate More :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to make use of the `navigationUri` parameter when you create the `ShellTile` via the `Create` method. The standard pattern is;

```
Uri mySecondaryPage = new Uri("/MySecondaryPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.Where(x => x.NavigationUri == mySecondaryPage).FirstOrDefault();
if (tile != null) {
  tile.Delete();
}

StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData() {
  Title = "Appears on the front",
  // Whatever number badge you want to appear 
  Count = 1, 
  // Front image
  BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Image.png", UriKind.Relative), 
  // Image for flip side
  BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/AnotherImage.png", UriKind.Relative), 
  BackTitle = "Appears on the back",
  BackContent = "As does this"
};

ShellTile.Create(mySecondaryPage, data);
```

When the user taps this icon it'll navigate directly to "MySecondaryPage.xaml"

There's some good documentation for this readily available on MSDN's [How to: Create, Delete, and Update Tiles for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202979%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) article.